# Are these "infinity" sequences true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

For $1\over 3$, you get $0.\overline3$, which is $0.33333...$.  The threes go on forever.  You can't ask "What happens if it ends in an eight?" because it simply doesn't end.

For SSSSS..., what if it ends in a T?  Well, an infinite series of Ss followed by a T would *never* have a T because it never ends.

There can be infinite points in a point, even a very small one.

Are they true or false?  I think they're true, aren't they?  If not, why not?

Comment: What do you mean by "there can be infinite points in a point"

Comment: For example, if I have just one point, any number of points can fit into there.

Comment: See my answer to the linked question.

Comment: Well, I really want answers, so I hope it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I already posted an answer to this question, on the suggested duplicate. Are you interested in having answers to a question that *you* asked, or are you interested in learning the answer to a question that you *asked*?

Comment: Wow.  You really did it this time...

Comment: I suspect the problem will go away (for you) once terms such as "point" and "can fit into there" are made sufficiently precise, although this is not really all that easy to do.

Comment: Okay, ten minutes and you already do this to me?

Comment: Any number of points can fit into a point depending on the sizes of the points, but infinity can happen.

Comment: I think that the accurate interpretation of these concepts took years of mathematical reflection by people who didn't just accept what they were told, but knew it wasn't quite there yet and went in search of new ideas. Some of those ideas turned out to be incredibly fruitful. The rigorous definition of the real numbers is one of them. I've just been rereading GH Hardy's "Pure Mathematics" - revolutionary in its day. Progress in clarity of notation and definition over the last century has been immense, even though the results have not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is to consider this as a limit. Note first that:

$$33333=\frac {10^5-1}3$$

Then $$333338=10\frac {10^5-1}3+8=\frac{10^6-10+24}3=\frac {10^6+14}3$$

Then $$0.333338=10^{-6}\cdot\frac {10^6+14}3=\frac {1+14\times 10^{-6}}3$$

Now if we have $r$ threes followed by an eight, the equivalent formula is $$\frac {1+14\times 10^{-(r+1)}}3=\frac 13+\frac {14}3\cdot10^{-(r+1)}$$

The value of this expression, as $r$ gets larger and larger, gets closer and closer to $\cfrac 13$ - we say that the limit is one third.

This may not be quite how you were thinking of the question - my daughter asks me questions like this sometimes, and I do my best to explain them. Really there isn't a last digit, and if you think about it you could add all sorts of noise at the end and still get the same limit.

But the insights which arise from your intuition helped mathematicians like Dedekind and Cauchy to define the real numbers and the meaning of limits, so that it made sense to have a single real number which was a limit of all kinds of different sequences in such a way that our decimal expansions of numbers still make sense.

Comment: I think that you're missing the point. The OP essentially asked about sequences indexed by $\omega+1$. They go allllll the way to infinity, and then have a point afterwards. (And as I wrote in my answer to the suggested duplicate, those things are mathematically sound; they just don't define real numbers. But that's fine, mathematics has so much more to offer than just real numbers!)

Comment: @AsafKaragila It depends a bit what level OP is at and how they are thinking about the question. I looked at the comments which were put up as I was writing this, and think your answer on the (very nearly exact) duplicate is sharp and good and interesting. I am never categorical with my daughters, and I began here "One thing you could do ..." for that reason. I note that some of the other answers on the linked question take the kind of approach I have suggested. But yours definitely helps to see that there is a potential world to explore beyond "the standard model".

Comment: @AsafKaragila This kind of question comes up often enough - maybe there is an interesting blog item on it?

Comment: I'm not that versed with the mathematical blogosphere, actually. Despite having a mathematical "blog". I guess I could write one, but time is scarce nowadays and I have much to do; I also don't know what I'd write in such post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There are occasional such posts on this site now. Anyhow, your answer to the duplicate seems to have been well recognised - and I voted for it, having been pointed in that direction. I'm hoping that what I said helped OP a bit.